# how to update nested object of array in useState hook in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, form-control, nested-object

I have a component that has nested objects in array:

```
  const [documentObj, setDocument] = useState({
    document_name: "",
    form_values: [
      {
        field_seq: null,
        is_mandatory: false,
        field_type: null,
        field_name: "",
        select_values: [
          {
            value: false,
            label: "",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
```

I'm trying to update the object properties, but when I try to update the object, it is saying can not reay properties [0]

this is how I'm updating it:

```
<Form.Control
 type="number"
 value={documentObj.form_values[0].field_seq}
 onChange={(event) => {
  setDocument((prevStyle) => ({
  ...prevStyle,
form_values: [
{
...prevStyle.form_values,
field_seq: event.target.value,
},
],
}));
}}
/>
</Form.Group>
```

Probably i need to write a function to handle all input value and need some help

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2**

It seems that `documentObj.form_values[0]` is unlikely to be `undefined` in the posted code, but maybe it could be in the actual project.

As an attempt to address the error perhaps also consider to check for `undefined` where this is used, such as in `value`:

```
value={documentObj.form_values[0]?.field_seq || ""}
```

**Update**

While not specified in the post, if `Form.Control` is from react-bootstrap, according to their [doc](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/form-control/#api) the `value` property need to be `string | arrayOf | number`.

Perhaps also try set an empty string `""` as the initial value of `field_seq`, so this component is fully controlled:

```
const [documentObj, setDocument] = useState({
  document_name: "",
  form_values: [
    {
      //  Initial value as empty string
      field_seq: "",
      is_mandatory: false,
      field_type: null,
      field_name: "",
      select_values: [
        {
          value: false,
          label: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

There might be other issues, but hope that this could still help locating some errors.

**Original**

Perhaps the intended property to read was `...prevStyle.form_values[0]`?

Not sure if there are other issues without checking the error message, but could probably try the following in `setDocument` to see if it improves:

```
<Form.Control
  type="number"
  value={documentObj.form_values[0].field_seq}
  onChange={(event) => {
    setDocument((prevStyle) => ({
      ...prevStyle,
      form_values: [
        {
          //  Added [0] here
          ...prevStyle.form_values[0],
          field_seq: event.target.value,
        },
      ],
    }));
  }}
/>
```

Comment: how about value elemenr? still getting same error.

Comment: @alimukhtor Not sure what else might be tried here without testing it, but what did the error message say?

Comment: documentObj.form_values[0].field_seq this is saying can not read properties of undefined [0]

Answer (score 0):

const [documentObj, setDocument] = useState({
document_name: "",
form_values: [
{
field_seq: null,
is_mandatory: false,
field_type: null,
field_name: "",
select_values: [
{
value: false,
label: "",
},
],
},
],
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

replacing the  items in `form_values` based on index

```
<Form.Control
      type="number"
      value={documentObj.form_values[0]?.field_seq ?? ''}
      onChange={(event) => {
        setDocument((prevStyle) => {
   
    
           const newFormValues = [];
    
           if (!!prevStyle.form_values?.length) {
                              // if the form_values was empty 
           const newFormValue = { 
                 // might want to include some default data
                 field_seq: event.target.value 
           }
               newFormValues.push(newFormValue)
           } else {
                //replace first item form_values 
                newFormValues = prevStyle.form_values.map((e, idx) => {
                       if (idx === 0) {
                           return {
                              ...e,
                              field_seq: event.target.value 
                           }
                       } else {
                            return e;
                       }
                })
           }
    
     
           return {
              ...prevStyle,
              form_values: newFormValues
           }
    
    }}
    />
    </Form.Group>
```

Hope it helps